# Изучаю основы less css. Есть готовый файл css. Нужно сделать исходный файл less до компиляции коалой

Tags: css, less

super.css:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  font-family: 'museo_reg', sans-serif;
}
section {
  padding: 4rem 0 8rem;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
button:focus,
input:focus,
a:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.feedback-forms-all {
  padding: 6rem 0 9rem 0;
}
.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'museo_bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}
.section-title .upper-icon-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #5ba2a9;
}
.section-title .upper-icon-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #5ba2a9;
}
.section-title .upper-icon-wrapper .upper-icon {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form-statement {
  padding: 6rem 0 0;
}
.feedback-form-title {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.feedback-form-title h3 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'museo_bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}
.feedback-form-title p {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
.feedback-form-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.4rem 4.5rem 1.4rem 1.4rem;
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  opacity: .5;
  color: #454545;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transitiosn: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.feedback-form-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.feedback-form-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.feedback-form-input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.feedback-form-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #515151;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.feedback-form-input:hover,
.feedback-form-input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
.feedback-form .input-user {
  background: url(../img/shared/feedback/person-icon.svg) right 1.5rem center no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form .input-phone {
  background: url(../img/shared/feedback/telephone-icon.svg) right 1.5rem center no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form-btn {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2rem 0;
  background-color: #5ba2a9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.feedback-form-btn:hover {
  background-color: #488389;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.feedback-form .title-feedback {
  display: block;
}
.feedback-form .description-feedback {
  display: block;
}
```

Сделал так:

super.less:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  font-family: "museo_reg", sans-serif;
}
section {
  padding: 4rem 0 0rem;
}
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
button:focus,
input:focus,
a:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.feedback-forms-all {
  padding: 6rem 0 9rem 0;
}
.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: "museo_bold", sans-serif;
  &.upper-icon-wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 0.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #5ba2a9;
  }
  &.upper-icon-wrapper::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5rem;
    height: 0.1rem;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #5ba2a9;
  }
  &.upper-icon-wrapper .upper-icon {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  }
}
.feedback-form-statement {
  padding: 6rem 0 0;
}
.feedback-form-title {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
    font-family: "museo_bold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #1b1b1b;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
  }
}
.feedback-form-input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.4rem 4.5rem 1.4rem 1.4rem;
  border: 2px solid #d0d0d0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: #454545;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transitiosn: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  &:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  &:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  &:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.feedback-form .input-user {
  background: url(../img/shared/feedback/person-icon.svg) right 1.5rem center
    no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form .input-phone {
  background: url(../img/shared/feedback/telephone-icon.svg) right 1.5rem center
    no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form-btn {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2rem 0;
  background-color: #5ba2a9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #488389;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
.feedback-form .title-feedback {
  display: block;
}
.feedback-form .description-feedback {
  display: block;
}
```

Как можно использовать переменные и миксины в этом примере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы понять где использовать миксины ищите повторения в вашем коде, их и заменяйте на миксины. Например у вас есть стили для картинок, в них меняется только название картинки:

```css
.mixins_pic(@name){
  background: url('../img/shared/feedback/@{name}-icon.svg') right 1.5rem center
  no-repeat;
  background-size: 2rem;
}
.feedback-form .input-user{
  .mixins_pic('person')
}
.feedback-form .input-phone {
  .mixins_pic('telephone')
}
```

То же самое можно сделать с блоком кода

```
content: "";
display: inline-block;
width: 1.5rem;
height: 0.1rem;
margin-bottom: 15px;
background-color: #5ba2a9;
```

или

```
color: #515151;
font-size: 1.5rem;
```

У вас повторяется значение transition, где-то оно 0.4s, где-то 0.3. Если вам одна десятая секунды не критична, поместите значение 0.3 или 0.4 в переменную и ссылайтесь на нее, где необходимо.

```css
@transition:0.3s;

.feedback-form-btn {
  -webkit-transition: @transition;
    transition: @transition;
}   
.feedback-form-input {
  color: #454545;
  -webkit-transition: @transition;
  -moz-transition: @transition;
  -ms-transitiosn: @transition;
  transition: @transition;
}
```